# "The movie is a portrait of a man without qualities, baffled by the emotions and needs of others . "

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

"The movie is a portrait of a man without qualities, baffled by the emotions and needs of others."

I know that 'baffled by emotions and needs ...' is modifying 'man', but why is the comma used there?

One of my friends says the comma was intended to separate 'without qualities' and 'baffled by emotions and needs ...', so that this 'baffled' phrase doesn't modify qualifies.

Some say it is a non-restrictive phrase.
If I think it's a non-restrictive phrase, then 'baffled by emotions and needs ...' would be able to also modify 'qualities', right?

Comment: I'd never encountered "**man without qualities**" before. Checking with Google, practically every use of that sequence relates to [*Musil's "The Man Without Qualities"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Without_Qualities) - a somewhat klunky translation from German that's nearly always *defined* when first referenced (because otherwise, the average native Anglophone reader would have no idea what it was supposed to mean). So it's a bad example usage anyway, but unquestionably ***baffled*** references preceding noun ***a man** [without qualities]*.

Answer (score 1):

"Without qualities" is being used in the sense of without excellence of disposition, good natural gifts (i.e. without good character, without vitues, etc). It describes the man in the example.

> **Quality**
>
> A. n.
>
> 1. With reference to a person
>    . . .
>
> c. Without article or poss. pron.: Excellence of disposition; good
> natural gifts.

Source: [OED.com Second Edition (1989)](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00194227)

The example sentence is basically a list of adjectives separated by a comma, which describe a man "without qualities, baffled by the emotions and [baffled by the] needs of others."

Comment: Thanks but i was asking is the phrase after comma  a non restrictive phrase because a comma before a phrase means that

Comment: @BlaBbaa - you could say that I suppose, but it's just a list of adjectives that describe a man.  The adjectives after the comma don't describe the "quality". They describe the man. "Without qualities" also describes the man.

Comment: Can the phrase still describe the man if i removed the comma

Comment: @BlaBbaa - no, it wouldn't make sense. You need the comma/s if you make a list. It's similar to "The bananas were long, yellow, sweet and tasty."